# Lines separated by newline character are not being displayed correctly within an WPF TextBlock

Tags: wpf, mvvm, visual-studio-2008, textblock

I have an WPF Textblock to which I bind a view model property, let's say, 'Lines'.

Lines view model property contains three lines separated by the newline character \r\n as below:

```
IDXXXAZZ000000000099898T<<<<<<\r\n9999999M8888778XXX<<<<<<<<<<<3\r\nXXXX<XXXXX<<XXXXXXX<XXXX<<<<<<
```

So I am trying to put them in the TextBlock as below:

```
IDXXXAZZ000000000099898T<<<<<<
9999999M8888778XXX<<<<<<<<<<<3
XXXX<XXXXX<<XXXXXXX<XXXX<<<<<<
```

As you can see above all three lines always have the same number of characters, 30 characters each one, but for some reason lines does not appear to end at the same point, that is, instead of displaying them like above, they are displayed like below:

[image]

I have tried below TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="11" 
           Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"                       
           Margin="0 10 0 0"
           Text="{Binding Path=Lines}" 
           FontFamily="Verdana" 
           FontSize="9" />
```

So what's the problem? type of font family? font size? I do not understand it.

Comment: Obviously, Verdana is not a monospaced font.

Comment: Opsss, I do not know this. Thanks. Using fixed width (also known as fixed pitch) fonts like Courier New, Consolas and Lucida Console works.